# MS-Word file is only showing strange characters

Tags: microsoft-word, symbols

I had my ms-word file working properly the whole week but today a virus started corrupting my ppt files and now I can't open them. I went to check my word file because i have something really important on it and when I opened I saw this:

[image]

I've tried lots of things to fix it but nothing worked.

The whole document is in symbols and it was a 300 page file. I really need a quick fix, or at least tell me if it's not possible to fix it so i stop trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you have restore points, you can recover a previous version of the file. I made **[this little tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/132087-shadowexplorer-recover-lost-files-folders.html#post1137368)** that shows you how.